# Expression Matching With MatchQ and HoldForm

Tags: pattern-matching

I am learning to work with MatchQ for pattern matching in expressions.  For instance:

```
MatchQ[x + y, Plus[_,__]]
```

returns True.

However,

```
MatchQ[1+1, Plus[_,__]]
```

returns False.

I believe the reason for this is that Mathematica has evaluated 1+1, and the structure of the expression has changed.

To check this:

```
FullForm[HoldForm[1+1]]
```

returns HoldForm[Plus[1,1]]

Ok.  Getting closer.

Where I am stuck is passing the unevaluated expression of 1+1 to MatchQ in functional format to test.

How would I structure MatchQ to evaluate the expression 1+1 as True?

Comment: `MatchQ` does not have any *Hold* attributes. Therefore, `Plus` is evaluated before it is passed into `MatchQ`.  Run the following to see the affect: `Trace[MatchQ[1 + 1, Plus[_, __]]]`.

Comment: Are you looking for `MatchQ[Unevaluated[1 + 1], Plus[_, __]]`?

Comment: Also you can check out `Inactive`, `IgnoringInactive`, *etc*.

Comment: Unevaluated was what I was looking for.  Thanks.